# Getting my USB wifi stick to work on Debian (squeeze)?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian-squeeze

I recently installed Debian-squeeze to multi-boot with vista on a HP desktop.
I have an Netgear WNA3100 wifi stick I use on Vista and am trying to get working with Debian. I followed the instructions I found on the Debian wiki and Ubuntu forums. I got the Broadcom drivers for xp and installed them using ndiswrapper on Debian. I also installed network-manager and network-manager gnome and its working fine. My main problem is that when I find my router in network-manager, it tries to connect, asks for password, tries to connect and asks for password, repeats this a few times, then doesn't connect. I wonder what the problem is and how it can be fixed.

I put a report of a few commands and relevant infomation as well.

info (formatted on pastebin): http://pastebin.com/fJMgZKFP

Comment: Do you have the drivers that came with it? Take a look at how [somebody on UbuntuForums did it](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9837221&postcount=10) ([part 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9979973&postcount=27)). Its a pretty ugly hack (and actually involves patching ndiswrapper), but it is reported to work.

Comment: i did patch the ndiswrapper and followed the instructions, butit doesn't work since i can't seem to connect to the network.